Left Join For Subset of Data
I'm having a difficult time describing what I'm attempting to do, so I thought it best just to make a short example and describe the output that I'm trying to achieve.
CREATE TABLE temp_data
(transact_dt_tm DATE
, letter CHAR(1));
CREATE TABLE temp_ref
(
letter CHAR(1)
, letter_seq INT);
INSERT INTO temp_data (transact_dt_tm,letter) VALUES (to_date('2023-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),'K');
INSERT INTO temp_data (transact_dt_tm,letter) VALUES (to_date('2023-01-02','YYYY-MM-DD'),'K');
INSERT INTO temp_data (transact_dt_tm,letter) VALUES (to_date('2023-01-02','YYYY-MM-DD'),'L');
INSERT INTO temp_data (transact_dt_tm,letter) VALUES (to_date('2023-01-03','YYYY-MM-DD'),'Q');
INSERT INTO temp_data (transact_dt_tm,letter) VALUES (to_date('2024-01-02','YYYY-MM-DD'),'Y');
INSERT INTO temp_data (transact_dt_tm,letter) VALUES (to_date('2024-01-03','YYYY-MM-DD'),'B');
INSERT INTO temp_ref (letter, letter_seq) values('Y',10);
INSERT INTO temp_ref (letter, letter_seq) values('B',20);
INSERT INTO temp_ref (letter, letter_seq) values('Q',30);
INSERT INTO temp_ref (letter, letter_seq) values('K',40);
INSERT INTO temp_ref (letter, letter_seq) values('L',50);

I'm selecting this data out and using a heat map to display the data as a grid, so I need an X and Y category values and a numeric value. In this case, my X will be the letter and my Y will be the years. I tried something like this:
SELECT
   to_char(td.transact_dt_tm,'YYYY') AS YEAR
    , tr.letter
    , count(td.TRANSACT_DT_TM)
FROM
    TEMP_DATA td
 
LEFT JOIN TEMP_REF tr ON tr.LETTER = td.LETTER 

GROUP BY 
   to_char(td.transact_dt_tm,'YYYY')
    , tr.LETTER_SEQ
    , tr.LETTER 
ORDER BY 
   to_char(td.transact_dt_tm,'YYYY')
    , tr.LETTER_SEQ;

Which outputs:



Year
Letter
Count




2023
Q
1


2023
K
2


2023
L
1


2024
Y
1


2024
B
1



The data is correct, but because of the way the heat map is generated, my X headers end not in the sequence that I want set based on the temp_ref table:



Year
Q
K
L
Y
B




2023
1
2
1




2024



1
1



What I want is for my data to be output like this:



Year
Letter
Count




2023
Y



2023
B



2023
Q
1


2023
K
2


2023
L
1


2024
Y
1


2024
B
1



I can make this happen for one year, if I do this:
SELECT 
    tr.LETTER 
    , nvl(to_char(td.TRANSACT_DT_TM,'YYYY'),'2023') AS year
    , count(td.LETTER)
FROM 
    TEMP_REF tr 
LEFT JOIN TEMP_DATA td ON td.LETTER = tr.LETTER 
AND td.TRANSACT_DT_TM < to_date('2023-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY tr.LETTER 
    , tr.LETTER_SEQ 
    , nvl(to_char(td.TRANSACT_DT_TM,'YYYY'),'2023')
ORDER BY tr.LETTER_SEQ

But because the second year of data has the letters that are missing from Year 1, when I do all years, the LEFT JOIN is already satisfied and doesn't add the missing letters.
My real data is obviously more complicated than this (I have 12 years of transactions across a few dozen "letters"). All I can think of is that I could make the first year be LEFT JOINED like above to get all of the letters and their sequences in the first year, then UNION that data set to the rest of the data. Is there a better way to achieve this? Thanks!

Why are there no expected output rows for 2024 & Q/K/L?

There are no expected outputs for future years because the plugin that I'm using to create the heat map appears to be ok with that. It simply needs the complete data set for the X values, sorted correctly on the first series. If there are gaps in the next series, it skips over them. However, in your answer, having those values as 0 or NULL works as well.

You appear to want a PARTITIONed OUTER JOIN:
SELECT td.year,
       tr.letter, 
       count(td.letter)
FROM   TEMP_REF tr
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transact_dt_tm) AS year,
                letter
         FROM   TEMP_DATA
       ) td
       PARTITION BY (td.year)
       ON tr.LETTER = td.LETTER 
GROUP BY 
       td.year,
       tr.LETTER_SEQ,
       tr.LETTER 
ORDER BY 
       td.year,
       tr.LETTER_SEQ;

Which, for the sample data, outputs:



YEAR
LETTER
COUNT(TD.LETTER)




2023
Y
0


2023
B
0


2023
Q
1


2023
K
2


2023
L
1


2024
Y
1


2024
B
1


2024
Q
0


2024
K
0


2024
L
0



fiddle
